# Keeping track of votes in a c# Windows Form app

Tags: c#, forms, input

I am trying to create a form that can keep track of a users vote. I have two buttons that a user can select to vote for which selection they like best. I want to have something in the middle that inputs the vote automatically when a selection is made.I'm not sure what tool would work best and what the code should be like?

So far I just have the messages for the votes, but I haven't been able to find what would work best to tally them when the button is selected:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 

    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void Eyes2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your vote!");
    }

    private void Eyes1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your vote!");
    }

}
```

Comment: We could start off by taking a look at what you currently have done

Comment: Question isn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need **two** counters (yes/no?), and some kind of control to display the current tallies?

How about starting simple with a [Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx) control?

> Label controls can also be used to add descriptive text to a Form to
>   provide the user with helpful information.

Something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 

    private int Yes_Tally = 0;
    private int No_Tally = 0;

    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTally();
    }

    private void Eyes1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Yes_Tally++;
        UpdateTally();
    }

    private void Eyes2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        No_Tally++;
        UpdateTally();
    }

    private void UpdateTally()
    {
        lblTally.Text = String.Format("Yes: {0}, No: {1}", Yes_Tally, No_Tally);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a counter, increase that counter each time the button is clicked.